# Can you access class attributes within a class outside of class methods?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I'm still sorta new to Python and I was wondering if there was a way to access class attributes within a class but outside class methods. Something like so:

```
class dummy:
   def __init__(self,var):
       self.var = var

   CONSTANT = var * 2

   def calculate(self,x):
       return (CONSTANT * x)
```

I've tried variations of this and could not get it to work. Is there a way to go about this? or is this just a bad idea?

Comment: You cannot obtain the value of an instance variable without an instance. You can define class variables, but it would make no sense to do that in `__init__`.

Comment: What does it mean to you that you have `CONSTANT`? How will you access that value?

Comment: Do you mean something like `type(self).CONSTANT = var*2` *inside* the instance method?

Comment: @quamrana so  the `CONSTANT` value would have been used in the class methods. I was thinking that it would be easier to have the `CONSTANT` outside the class methods so that I wouldn't need to define it in every class method where its used.

Comment: What is it you're hoping to achieve here? [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: But surely you meant to write: `self.CONSTANT = var * 2` as the second line of the `__init__()` method. Then all other methods can access `self.CONSTANT` without having to do the calculation.

Comment: @quamrana I should've thought of that. That would work perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no

Longer answer: Careful with your terminology, you're referencing the wrong things. I think you're *actual* question is, "Can you access instance attributes while inside class scope, but outside of instance method definitions"?

> Is there a way to go about this? or is this just a bad idea?

Can't really be answered, as you haven't really described what/why you're trying to do. All you've shown is "how something doesn't work".